# Ski areas rules-of-thumb south, north, east, west slope?

Tags: europe, skiing, alps

Are there any rules of thumb when choosing a skiing area?
I'm looking at google maps and browsing ratings, but are there any rules of thumb such as 'avoid north-oriented slopes' or something?

Height, i've already learned makes a huge difference in terms of chances of actual snow.

Comment: the fact is there's no really general solution here - unlike with wine!   Great question.  Happy new year. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have skied on slopes facing in all directions. At the end of the day, the slopes are where it is most convenient to build a lift from the valley. There are places like Obertauern (in the Austrian state of Salzburg) which have slopes on all sides of the valley and the mountains’ topography is the basis of your decision where to go.

That said, on the northern hemisphere the obvious difference is that a North-facing slopes will be more in the shade while a South-facing one will be in the sun most of the afternoon (reverse for the southern hemisphere). If temperatures are more on the warmer side, the snow quality on South-facing slopes will deteriorate more rapidly as they get the direct burn of the sun so a North-facing slopes can give better snow conditions. If it is rather cold, the chance of you freezing your important body parts off is higher on the North-facing slope as there is less sun. And if there is less sunlight due to a dense but high cloud cover, your chances of visibility are slightly higher on the South side. If it switches between a little too warm and a little too cold, you will get more ice on the South-facing slope.

It cannot be said which side will receive more snowfall; that depends more on the weather conditions than anything else.

You can transfer all these points to East/West slopes of you think about early sunlight (East) versus late sunlight (West).

Comment: The direction a slope faces will have a very strong effect on how much snowfall it receives—it’s just going to be different for every mountain. In many places, storm systems disproportionately come from a particular direction, and in many places those storms are stopped by the mountains—so that the far side gets vastly less precipitation than the storm-facing side does. But which slope faces into the storms is going to depend on a ton of factors, and I’m sure there are exceptions—one can imagine a mountain with higher mountains behind, where the far slope gets more than the “storm-facing” one.

Comment: Nothing like first run of the day down a crunchy, groomed North slope on a cold New England morning.